# Sublime2 Parse Error

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm getting an error in Sublime2 SFTP.

Error parsing sftp-config.json file:
No JSON object could be decoded

I'm not sure what is going. Help is appreciated. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling the SFTP plugin but that didn't fix it.

Here is my code:

```
{
    // The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
    // Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

    // sftp, ftp or ftps
    "type": "sftp",

    "save_before_upload": true,
    "upload_on_save": false,
    "sync_down_on_open": false,
    "sync_skip_deletes": false,
    "sync_same_age": true,
    "confirm_downloads": false,
    "confirm_sync": true,
    "confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

    "host": "54.173.65.194",
    "user": "brent",
    //"password": "password",
    //"port": "22",

    "remote_path": "/example",
    "ignore_regexes": [
        "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
        "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
        "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
    ],
    //"file_permissions": "664",
    //"dir_permissions": "775",

    //"extra_list_connections": 0,

    "connect_timeout": 30,
    //"keepalive": 120,
    //"ftp_passive_mode": true,
    //"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
    //"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
    //"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

    //"preserve_modification_times": false,
    //"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
    //"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
    //"remote_locale": "C",
    //"allow_config_upload": false,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User/sftp_servers
and delete the file that is causing the error
this sftp_server folder contains all your existing server connection config so you can decide which one is causing the problem  by reading the error properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think  it might be the','(comma) after the connect_timeout.  Javscript/json doesn't allow trailing commas on the last item in a list, unlike Python.

Comment: thanks. I tried that but still brought up the error.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by uninstalling Sublime 2, removing all preferences, and reinstalling. It works now.

Answer (score 0):

On my MacOS it was non-json file `app.py` inside (could be another file)

```
/Users/<your_username>/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/sftp_servers
```

When I deleted it error disappeared